# SSDT disappeared! in VS 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sql-server-data-tools

I have started to prefer SSDT to SQL Management studio. But suddenly when I needed it I could not find `SQL Server Object Explorer` in view menu.

[image]

Not sure who took it away, I recently pushed update-2 for visual studio.

[image]

I could not locate stand-alone version of [SSDT for VS-2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh297027)

Can any one please save me from re-installing Visual Studio :-(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2014/01/30/ssdt-and-visual-studio-versions.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:%20ssdtblog%20%28SQL%20Server%20Developer%20Tools%20Team%20Blog%29) on MSDN SSDT is now an integrated part of VS:

> **Visual Studio 2013** - VS 2013 now has SQL Server tooling built in and
>   shipped as part of the core product.  Database Projects, SQL tools
>   (such as schema compare & data compare), and the online experiences
>   through SSOX are all included with the RTM version.  We have full
>   project and SSOX support in VS Express for Web and Express for Windows
>   Desktop, so we have discontinued our stand-alone integrated shell
>   offering.

When I looked at the `Extensions and Updates`in VS2013 I had an update available for [SQL Server Data Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/hh297027) and when I clicked it I got a downloadable installer (SSDTsetup.exe) which might be what you are looking for.

The link that gave the download was this: [go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=393521&clcid=0x409](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=393521&clcid=0x409)