# Visual Studio 2013 incompatibility with MS SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-data-tools, sql-server-2014

I downloaded MS SQL Server 2014 Enterprise Edition from MSDN. I want to do a server backend in C# and MS SQL, but the problem is, whenever I want to do something with DB in Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate it just tells me this

```
===================================

An incompatible SQL Server version was detected. (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Tools.SqlEditor)
------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Tools.SqlEditor.DataModel.SqlConnectionStrategy.ValidateConnectionForEditor(UIConnectionInfo ci, IServerType server)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.ConnectionDlg.Connector.ConnectionThreadUser()
```

Honestly, I don't know what is going on, or why tells me that VS is incompatible with SQL server.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You should update SSDT to 2014, you can download it here:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh297027

Read more about support for SQL Server 2014 on this blog: [SQL Server Data Tools for SQL Server 2014 is available](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2014/03/25/sql-server-data-tools-for-sql-server-2014-is-available.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20ssdtblog%20%28SQL%20Server%20Developer%20Tools%20Team%20Blog%29)

From the post:

> For Visual Studio 2013 download check the Visual Studio update channel
>   (Tools –> Extensions and Updates –> Updates) for this update.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 12):

I'm guessing that your VS2013 isn't fully updated and that you need to update the database tooling component (SSDT) for SQL2014. I posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24222130/1175077) on this a couple of days ago with some instructions.

Look at the **Extensions and Updates** in VS2013 and there should be an update available for SQL Server Data Tools.

Answer (score 3):

SSDT didn't have support for SQL Server 2014 until a release in Oct2013.

Update your SSDT here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/data/tools.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Until late January only SQL Server 2014 CTP was available (Community Technology Preview) and not as a RTM; which was not supported by tools like Visual Studio.

But now new Data tools are available, you can download the same and upgrade to it.

Get it from here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh297027