# Can't see SQL Server table data in Server Explorer Window

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, sql-server-express

In my asp.net MVC application I created the database and then went to server explorer and I select one table and select open table data. I received the following error message.

[image]

Here is my connection string

```
<add name="YogaBandy" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\YogaBandy.mdf;Initial Catalog=YogaBandy;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I'm using VS 2013, asp.net mvc 5 and sql server express 2014 and have most if not all updates installed for everything.

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24351741/3242721)?

Comment: this worked. I updated and upgraded everything.

Comment: Glad to hear that, I guess you can delete this question as it provides no added value.