# Install order for Visual Studio 2013 and SQL Server 2014

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2014

Which order should these be installed in? I have read in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24351741/visual-studio-2013-incompatibility-with-ms-sql-server) that VS2013 requires an update to work with SQL Server 2014.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter. The two products do not conflict and side-by-side installation is supported in any order.

After installing VS you'll need to then install the latest SSDT version for SQL Server 2014 support. SSDT is s component of Visual Studio, not SQL Server.